# Doxygen comments not running in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, doxygen

I read that since Xcode 5 doxygen comments are recognized automatically. I have Xcode 6.3 and not appears these comments.

Have I to enable any option in Xcode??

I commented my methods as:

```
/**
* bla bla bla
*/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add * when you start a new line. For example:

```
/**
 *  Description
 *
 *  @param param1 param1 description
 *  @param param2 param2 description
 *
 *  @return return value description
 */
- (id) myMethodWithParam:(id)param1 andParam:(id)param2
```

I recommand you to add [VVDocumenter-Xcode](https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode) plugin.

You are right, it works without *. But you need to add the prototype of your method into your header file.